# How to compile a web project with Weblogic dependencies

Tags: java, maven, weblogic, classpath, single-sign-on

I'm trying to implement SSO for a web project that will be deployed on Weblogic. In the examples that I found the user identity is retrieved using weblogic's inner classes e.g. :

```
import weblogic.security.Security;
...        
Subject subject = Security.getCurrentSubject();
```

I believe a jar containing this "weblogic.security.Security" is in weblogic's classpath, but how am I supposed to compile the project? This dependency is not available from maven so there's no way to mark it as "provided".

Is there a common solution to this problem or I should get this jar from the weblogic directory and add it to the project's classpath?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will have to get the jar, add it to your local maven repository (or your organisation one, generally nexus or artifactory) and set the scope as provided.

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13702/maven_deployer.htm for an example on how to deploy your jar in your local maven repo.